# How to get the sequence name for a serial column

Tags: postgresql, sequence, greenplum

As far as I can tell, this query should show the expression for the new value of a serial column:

```
select d.adsrc
from (
 SELECT a.attrelid, a.attnum, n.nspname, c.relname, a.attname
 FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a, pg_namespace n, pg_class c
 WHERE a.attnum > 0
 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 AND a.attrelid = c.oid
 and c.relkind not in ('S','v')
 and c.relnamespace = n.oid
 and n.nspname not in ('pg_catalog','pg_toast','information_schema')
) x
left join pg_attrdef d on d.adrelid = x.attrelid and d.adnum = x.attnum
where x.relname = 'table_name' and x.nspname = 'schema_name' and x.attname = 'column_name'
;
```

It works most of the time, but if I rename the sequence, the new name is not reflected in the result of the query - it continues to show the original name of the sequence. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the comments, [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) said:

> Are you using Greenplum or Postgres? In Postgres you can just use `pg_get_serial_sequence`

You can find [the docs here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE)

> `pg_get_serial_sequence` returns the name of the sequence associated with a column, or NULL if no sequence is associated with the column. The first input parameter is a table name with optional schema, and the second parameter is a column name. Because the first parameter is potentially a schema and table, it is not treated as a double-quoted identifier, meaning it is lower cased by default, while the second parameter, being just a column name, is treated as double-quoted and has its case preserved. The function returns a value suitably formatted for passing to sequence functions (see [Section 9.16](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html)). This association can be modified or removed with `ALTER SEQUENCE OWNED BY`. (The function probably should have been called `pg_get_owned_sequence`; its current name reflects the fact that it's typically used with `serial` or `bigserial` columns.)